# Insert into with select and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to do a `INSERT INTO` with select and group by, like this:

```
INSERT INTO client(name, age, last_name, id_city)
select l.name_client, l.age_client, l.last_name, l.id_city
from list_request l 
inner join product pd
  on l.id = pd.id_list_request;
```

When i run it, 4 results appear, repeated, but i only need one.

What can i do to solve this, i try to use GROUP BY, but is not work, or i don't know how to use it.

Edit: sorry, I forgot 2 columns, but I just need to group by name and age.

Comment: try `select distinct  l.name_client, l.age_client` :-)

Comment: How did you try to use the `group by` statement?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample data and required result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
insert into client(name, age)
select 
  l.name_client, 
  l.age_client
from 
  list_request l 

  inner join product pd on 
    l.id = pd.id_list_request
group by
  l.name_client,
  l.age_client;
```

If that doesn't work can you print out what you are getting with just the select and add it to your question?